# Integration by Parts and Reduction Formula of $\int\tan^n(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

The integral of:
$$\int\tan^n(x)dx$$

I found this proof online for the answer and it went like this:
$$\int\tan^{n-2}(x)\tan^2(x)dx$$
$$\int\tan^{n-2}(x)(\sec^2(x)-1)dx$$
$$\int\tan^{n-2}(x)\sec^2(x)dx-\int\tan^{n-2}(x)dx$$
Then using u-substitution it yielded the reduction formula:
$$\frac{\tan^{n-1}(x)}{n-1}-\int\tan^{n-2}dx$$

I tried using integration by parts because this is in the integration by parts:
I set my $u=\tan^n(x)$ and my $du=\frac{\tan^{n-1}(x)}{n-1}\sec^2(x)$, and $dv=dx$

I achieve this expression:

$$x\tan^n(x)-\frac{1}{n-1}\int x\tan^{n-1}(x)\sec^2(x)dx$$

And then if I continue working I set it like this:

I use u-substitution to evaluate the integral setting my $u=\tan(x)$, and $x=\tan^{-1}(u)$, and $du=\sec^2(x)dx$

Then I get:
$$x\tan^n(x)-\frac{1}{n-1}\int\tan^{-1}(u)u^{n-1}du$$
Then I used integration by parts and got:

$$x\tan^n(x)-\frac{1}{n-1}[\frac{\tan^{-1}(u)u^n}{n}-\frac{1}{n}\int\frac{u^n}{u^2+1}du]$$

If I keep going down this way do I get the reduction formula above?

Comment: *Is there a way to keep going down this path, and still get the same conclusion* What do you mean by that ?

Comment: @StephenG Is there a method to attain the same answer from the conclusion I reached?

Comment: That's still vague.  What do you mean by "same answer" and what do you mean by "same conclusion" ?  What are you trying to find out ?  I don't know what you expect to happen.

Comment: This is the natural way to obtain the reduction formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reduction formula for $\int tan^n x dx$ is obtained as follows.

For positive integer $n$

$I_n$ = $\int tan^n x dx$ = $\int tan^{n-2}$$x$ $\tan^2x$ $dx$ = $\int tan^{n-2}$$x$ ($\sec^2x$$-1)$$dx$

= $\int tan^{n-2}$$x$ $\sec^2x$$dx$ - $\int tan^{n-2}$$x$ $dx$

=$\frac{tan^{n-1}x}{n-1}$ $-$ $I_{n-2}$

Thus, $I_n$ $=$ $\frac{tan^{n-1}x}{n-1}$ $-$ $I_{n-2}$.

Now

If $n$ is positive integer

$\int tan^n x dx$ = $\frac{tan^{n-1}x}{n-1}$ $-$ $\frac{tan^{n-3}x}{n-3}$ $+$$\frac{tan^{n-5}x}{n-5}$ $-$ $.$ $.$ $.$

If $n$ be odd, the last term is ${(-1)}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ $\int tan x $ $dx$ = ${(-1)}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ $\ln$ $\sec x$.

If $n$ be even, the last term is ${(-1)}^{\frac{n+2}{2}}$ $\int tan^2 x $ $dx$ = ${(-1)}^{\frac{n+2}{2}}$ ($\tan x -x)$.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. OP is looking for ways other than $u-substituion$

Comment: I used neither integration by parts nor any 'u' substitution.

Comment: Seriously? It's the exact solution in OP's question. They wanted to find another method to get to the same answer.

Comment: Also, The u-sub is implicit when you had $\int \tan^{n-2} x \sec^2 x dx = \frac{\tan^{n-1} x}{n-1}$

Comment: Just @Dylan stated, this answer is a reiteration of the solution I found online.